# Javascript shorten GET values

Tags: javascript, arrays, compression

I am working on an app in which you can select numerous elements in a map by dragging a rectangle or polygon selection around them. After that the user can make some additional settings, presses a send button and gets to a result page. I want to send the request with GET so that the user can for example save the link.

My problem is that the number of elements that are selected can be very large (around 1000) so if I base64_encode an array with all element IDs the URL becomes easily too large. It's not an option to send just the polygon or rectangle coordinates because the user is allowed to deselect single buoys manually.

So my question is how can I efficiently compress an array of integers to a short string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I used in the last place was using not GET but store everything after the #. For the hash string there are no size restrictions so even large amounts of data can be stored there.